# MongoDB Content Management Query (Grouping and Distinct in SQL)

Tags: mysql, mongodb, entity-relationship

I am trying to manage Media uploaded to a server and delete the files, when they are not used anymore.

An media file can be linked by multiple entries, one entry can link exactly one media file "content" but I can delete the content and add a new one.

One Media File consists of a Thumbnail, a Preview Image, Mobile, SD and HD video, Audio in Low Quality and High Quality or a Downloadable file (PDF, PPT, Word, etc)

When the media is "deleted" from the last entry, it should be deleted.

My Idea comes from MySQL, There I would do something like:

Having a Table Media with all the links to the media files and a cross table between my "entries" table and the media table.

In the cross table, I would delete the corresponding row, when the entry was deleted or a new media was uploaded (and so the linking was deleted)

Anytime, my cronjob for deleting the media runs, I would check which entry of the media table is not in the crosstable and delete those entries.

How can I do that in MongoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is a little irritating because you say "one entry can link exactly one media file" and "[...] and a cross table between my entries table and the media table". If you mean a linker table, why would you need that in MySQL?

Anyway, you could do it in essentially the same way, no matter whether you want an M:N or a 1:N relation:

```
entry { 
   _id : ObjectId("..."),
   // 1:N
   mediaId : ObjectId("..."),
   // M:N
   mediaIds : [ ObjectId("..."), ... ]
   ...
}

media { 
   _id : ObjectId("..."),
   ...
}
```

Your worker would have to run over all media documents and check whether a corresponding entry exists. Since that can be computationally expensive, it might be worthwhile to keep a `refCount` in each media document which is incremented when a new entry referring to that medium is inserted, and decremented on delete. Since that counter can, in very rare cases, be incorrect (race conditions, client/db crashes or network partitions between the two actions), you might want make sure there are indeed no references left before actually deleting.

Comment: The reason why I would use a cross table comes from the non-sql-world, using sql in some projects and nosql in other is a bit confusing ;-)